# Machine boots GENERIC kernel after freebsd-update install

Tags: freebsd

The last two times I ran `freebsd-update install` the machine (re)booted from the `GENERIC` kernel instead of my custom kernel.

As suggested by [Freebsd Update](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/updating-upgrading-freebsdupdate.html) (section 25.2.2) I have a `GENERIC` kernel in `/boot/GENERIC`:

> Note: It is a good idea to always keep a copy of the GENERIC kernel in /boot/GENERIC. It will be helpful in diagnosing a variety of problems, and in performing version upgrades using freebsd-update as described in Section 25.2.3.

Now this breaks my remote access to the machine because networking will not properly do its job with `GENERIC` (the main reason being the missing `dummynet` support, I believe).

Anyways: I am not sure if a) this behaviour is by design (e.g. it is not clear if a custom kernel will boot after the upgrade so `GENERIC` is booted if available) and b) if I could circumvent this by always rebuilding my custom kernel after running `freebsd-update install` and before rebooting.

b) is supported by the fact that the machine successfully boots from my custom kernel after I physically access it and recompile my kernel.

Or did I get something about `freebsd-update` completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put this to your `/boot/loader.conf`?

```
dummynet_load="YES"
```

Should work with GENERIC kernel, too.

Comment: No, I have not tried this. But I will :) And it would still be great to know if this behaviour is by design anyway.

Comment: Well with the generic kernel you are supposed to put more exotic things such as dummynet to /boot/loader.conf anyway, I think.

Comment: OK. But dummynet is only on the sideline of my question. What really nags me is why the generic kernel is booted at all. I mean, I don't technically *have* to have it around, do I?